# Angular not fetching all modules

Tags: angular

I am trying to run an angular application but after doing ng serve i am getting the below error.

Is there a way to automatically install all these modules without manually installing them?

I ran the command and it got the node_modules directory but it is still missing these modules.

Thanks

```
   ERROR in src/app/calendar/calendar.module.ts(16,9): error TS2554: Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 0.
src/app/cards/cards.module.ts(5,33): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@swimlane/ngx-charts'.
src/app/charts/chartist/chartist.component.ts(2,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'chartist'.
src/app/charts/chartist/chartist.component.ts(3,39): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ng-chartist/dist/chartist.component'.
src/app/charts/charts.module.ts(4,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ng2-charts'.
src/app/charts/charts.module.ts(5,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ng-chartist'.
src/app/charts/charts.module.ts(6,33): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@swimlane/ngx-charts'.
src/app/chat-ngrx/chat-ngrx.component.ts(33,5): error TS2581: Cannot find name '$'. Do you need to install type definitions for jQuery? Try `npm i @types/jquery`.
src/app/chat-ngrx/chat-ngrx.module.ts(5,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'videogular2/core'.
src/app/chat-ngrx/chat-ngrx.module.ts(6,34): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'videogular2/controls'.
src/app/chat-ngrx/chat-ngrx.module.ts(7,37): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'videogular2/overlay-play'.
src/app/chat-ngrx/chat-ngrx.module.ts(8,35): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'videogular2/buffering'.
src/app/chat/chat.component.ts(28,5): error TS2581: Cannot find name '$'. Do you need to install type definitions for jQuery? Try `npm i @types/jquery`.
src/app/chat/chat.module.ts(4,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'videogular2/core'.
src/app/chat/chat.module.ts(5,34): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'videogular2/controls'.
src/app/chat/chat.module.ts(6,37): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'videogular2/overlay-play'.
src/app/chat/chat.module.ts(7,35): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'videogular2/buffering'.
src/app/components/bootstrap/carousel/carousel.component.ts(14,7): error TS2581: Cannot find name '$'. Do you need to install type definitions for jQuery? Try `npm i @types/jquery`.
src/app/components/extra/drag-drop/drag-drop.component.ts(43,25): error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '(groupName?: string) => Observable<{ name: string; el: Element; source: Element; }>'.
src/app/components/extra/drag-drop/drag-drop.component.ts(46,25): error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '(groupName?: string) => Observable<{ name: string; el: Element; target: Element; source: Element; sibling: Element; }>'.
src/app/components/extra/drag-drop/drag-drop.component.ts(49,25): error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '(groupName?: string) => Observable<{ name: string; el: Element; container: Element; source: Element; }>'.
src/app/components/extra/drag-drop/drag-drop.component.ts(53,24): error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '(groupName?: string) => Observable<{ name: string; el: Element; container: Element; source: Element; }>'.
src/app/components/extra/drag-drop/drag-drop.component.ts(56,30): error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '<T = any>(groupName?: string) => Observable<{ name: string; el: Element; target: Element; source: Element; sibling: Element; item: T; sourceMod
el: T[]; targetModel: T[]; sourceIndex: number; targetIndex: number; }>'.
src/app/components/extra/drag-drop/drag-drop.component.ts(59,32): error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '<T = any>(groupName?: string) => Observable<{ name: string; el: Element; container: Element; source: Element; item: T; sourceModel: T[]; source
Index: number; }>'.
src/app/components/extra/editor/editor.component.ts(5,38): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ngx-quill/src/quill-editor.component'.
src/app/components/extra/tour/tour.component.ts(13,5): error TS2581: Cannot find name '$'. Do you need to install type definitions for jQuery? Try `npm i @types/jquery`.
src/app/components/extra/tour/tour.component.ts(14,5): error TS2581: Cannot find name '$'. Do you need to install type definitions for jQuery? Try `npm i @types/jquery`.
src/app/components/extra/tour/tour.component.ts(15,5): error TS2581: Cannot find name '$'. Do you need to install type definitions for jQuery? Try `npm i @types/jquery`.
src/app/components/extra/upload/upload.component.ts(2,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ng2-file-upload/ng2-file-upload'.
src/app/components/ui-components.module.ts(6,34): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ng2-file-upload/ng2-file-upload'.
src/app/components/ui-components.module.ts(9,29): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ngx-quill'.
src/app/components/ui-components.module.ts(12,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ngx-chips'.
src/app/components/ui-components.module.ts(14,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ngx-ui-switch'.
src/app/components/ui-components.module.ts(15,30): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'videogular2/core'.
src/app/components/ui-components.module.ts(16,34): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'videogular2/controls'.
src/app/components/ui-components.module.ts(17,37): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'videogular2/overlay-play'.
src/app/components/ui-components.module.ts(18,35): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'videogular2/buffering'.
src/app/customer/customer.module.ts(5,33): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@swimlane/ngx-charts'.
src/app/dashboard/analytics/analytics.component.ts(2,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'chartist'.
src/app/dashboard/analytics/analytics.component.ts(3,39): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ng-chartist/dist/chartist.component'.
src/app/dashboard/dashboard.module.ts(5,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ng-chartist'.
src/app/dashboard/eCommerce/eCommerce.component.ts(2,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'chartist'.
src/app/dashboard/eCommerce/eCommerce.component.ts(3,39): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ng-chartist/dist/chartist.component'.
src/app/data-tables/country/country.component.ts(2,36): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release'.
src/app/data-tables/customer-file/customer-file.component.ts(2,36): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release'.
src/app/data-tables/customer-tariff-af/customer-tariff-af.component.ts(2,36): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release'.
src/app/data-tables/customer-tariff/customer-tariff.component.ts(2,36): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release'.
src/app/data-tables/data-tables.module.ts(4,36): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@swimlane/ngx-datatable'.
src/app/data-tables/filter/dt-filter.component.ts(2,36): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release'.
src/app/data-tables/service-code/service-code.component.ts(2,36): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release'.
src/app/data-tables/shipment/shipment.component.ts(2,36): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release'.
src/app/data-tables/user-list/user-list.component.ts(2,36): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release'.
src/app/forms/forms.module.ts(7,35): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ng2-validation'.
src/app/forms/forms.module.ts(8,34): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ng2-archwizard'.
src/app/pages/content-pages/coming-soon/coming-soon-page.component.ts(13,9): error TS2581: Cannot find name '$'. Do you need to install type definitions for jQuery? Try `npm i @types/jquery`.
src/app/pages/content-pages/coming-soon/coming-soon-page.component.ts(15,9): error TS2581: Cannot find name '$'. Do you need to install type definitions for jQuery? Try `npm i @types/jquery`.
src/app/pages/full-pages/full-pages.module.ts(6,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ng-chartist'.
src/app/shared/customizer/customizer.component.ts(12,5): error TS2581: Cannot find name '$'. Do you need to install type definitions for jQuery? Try `npm i @types/jquery`.
src/app/shared/data/sweet-alerts.ts(1,18): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'sweetalert2'.
src/app/shared/notification-sidebar/notification-sidebar.component.ts(12,5): error TS2581: Cannot find name '$'. Do you need to install type definitions for jQuery? Try `npm i @types/jquery`.
src/app/shared/shared.module.ts(7,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ngx-ui-switch'.
src/app/tables/tables.module.ts(4,37): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ng2-smart-table'.
src/app/ui-kit/syntax-highlighter/syntax-highlighter.component.ts(13,9): error TS2581: Cannot find name '$'. Do you need to install type definitions for jQuery? Try `npm i @types/jquery`.
src/app/ui-kit/text-utilities/text-utilities.component.ts(13,9): error TS2581: Cannot find name '$'. Do you need to install type definitions for jQuery? Try `npm i @types/jquery`.
```

Comment: head the the main root where the package.json is in terminal and run `npm install`

Comment: you have to do npm install where you have package.json but keep an eye on the console to see if there are any errors.

Comment: i did npm install but it didnot install anything new. below is the console

Comment: D:\angularnew2\angularnew3>npm install
npm WARN @agm/core@1.0.0-beta.5 requires a peer of @angular/common@^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

Comment: npm WARN @agm/core@1.0.0-beta.5 requires a peer of @angular/core@^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ngrx/store@6.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

Comment: npm WARN ng-snotify@4.3.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

up to date in 8.198s